# Text-to-speech reading queue?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-chrome-to-phone, reading

Anything similar to InstaPaper/Chrome to Phone, but with reading (text-to-speech) capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

InstaFetch ([Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.immortal.instafetch) / [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.immortal.instafetchpro.am)) is a InstaPaper client that has both the ability to download the webpages for offline use, and to read them aloud with the text to speech engine. There is both a free and a pay version. (BTW: For text to speech I use Ivona - it is free for now and produces amazing quality.)